# create legend from colors saved in const

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have chart, where I'm changing the color based on the value of the variable. For this purpose I'm using datas.map

```
const colours = datas.map((value) => value < 0 ? 'red' : 'green'); //changing color based on variable
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
        labels: label,
        datasets: [{
          label: ['positive', 'negative'], //legend to change
          borderColor: colours, 
          backgroundColor: colours,
          data: datas
        }]
     },
```

[image: chart.js example]

But, it is not possible to add legend with green and red color, only the red one shows. Is it possible to somehow add legend with both colors, where description for green one would be positive and for red negative?

Comment: What `datas` contains?

Comment: it's array full of numbers like [25,-45,88,192,-145,...]. If the number is positive, it is shown with green color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you are trying to do you need to separate datasets ie. one for negative values and other for positive values.

```
var positiveData = datas.filter(function (value) { return value > 0; });
var negativeData = datas.filter(function (value) { return value < 0; });

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
     type: 'bar',
     data: {
        labels: label,
        datasets: [{
          label: 'positive', //legend to change
          borderColor: 'green', 
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          data: positiveData 
        },
        {
          label: 'negative', //legend to change
          borderColor: 'red', 
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          data: negativeData 
        }]
     }
});
```

Comment: Use `datas.filter` to get `positiveData` and `negativeData`.